# Body not 100% height but 100% Viewport

Tags: html, css, height

https://jsfiddle.net/nprq5LLo/

Simple project I started working on , problem is that the body isnt 100% height of the document, its 100% of the viewport. Which is an issue since I want to use full-screen elements in future for it.

```
  html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
```

having html and body defined with 100% width and height and removing padding and margin did nothing to resolve the issue , i ran thru this type of questions in stackoverflow but none of the solutions were usefull for me.

I've tried adding lorems to make the page scrollable ,but the actual height of the body is as much as the viewport is , the content below is visible though.

Any ideas how we can solve this issue?

Comment: Set ```margin-top: 0;``` to ```h1``` and your issue will be fixed.

Comment: na brother, body remains the size of the viewport... this only shoves the body to stick to the top, this isnt a problem for me , i want the body to wrap the whole content and have its proper height :/

Comment: If you don't set a height for the body, it will automatically have the height of its content.

Comment: Do you want the body to be fullscreen and not scroll if content is more than that?

Comment: no I want a standart body , scrollable as it is now but with proper height ,since if u scroll down on the jfiddle the body's border will show height of only the current viewport and it will stick it to the top ,so all content is actually escaping it(overflowing), example if I make a fullscreen wrap, it will only wrap the highest point of the document with the height of the viewport and I dont want that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to make sure your height is at least 100% but then it grows with content, then instead of using `height: 100%` you should use `min-height: 100%`.

However, on your example, you may wonder why even if there's no enough content you still get a vertical scroll bar. That's because the `h1`'s margin-top is displacing the parent and making your body not start at the very top but rather at 0.67em (which is the h1's top margin on, for example, Google Chrome's User Agent by default).

There are many ways to solve this. You can:

- add a `padding-top: 1px` to the `.header`. If you want to be pixel perfect you can also add `margin-top: -1px`.
- add `overflow: auto` to the `.header`.
- remove the `margin-top` of the `h1` if you don't need it

Here's an implementation that uses `min-height: 100%` on body and also uses `overflow: auto` on the `.header`.
See how the body takes *at least* 100% of the height of the viewport, or its content's height if it's bigger than 100%. https://jsfiddle.net/nprq5LLo/7/

Comment: Well what do I know about life , it worked...
Thank you brother ,I marked you as the ANSWER and upvoted , tested in this example - https://jsfiddle.net/nprq5LLo/6/ 
if u remove the min-height the borders of the body show that it goes back to only 1 viewport height, thanks again

Comment: Edited the URL to the correct fiddle, you're right. My bad!